# How handle correctly delete action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am looking for the best practices how to handle correctly delete action.

For example I have array of photos in my reducer. 
And one of features is ability to select them to delete.
I have decided to store items that selected in react state. I store array of IDs.

So after delete action I have to remove photos from redux store and clear selected array in react state.

My suggestion was to subscribe on promise and do something like below:

```
 this.props.deletePhotos(selected)
.then(() => {
   this.setState({ selected: [] })
 })
.catch((err) => {
   console.log(err)
})
```

but guys have said that it is a bad practice. Is it true? How to change it in right way?

Answer (score 0):

The main principle you need to adhere to is that your state should always be valid. By using a promise, you are deleting the photos, rendering an invalid state, and then updating the react state. Even if such a render does is insignificant, it's not great practice.

You could just not set the state in the promise:

```js
const selected = this.state.selected
this.props.deletePhotos(selected)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
this.setState({selected: []})
```

Alternatively, and if you wanted to do something more complicated than clearing, you could use `getDerivedStateFromProps` and modify the state if relevant props were changed which may have come from redux.

Another alternative is that if you're done with the input, you would simply just not render the component in the next render and the state would be cleared automatically since it would be unmounted.

Comment: I don't store photos on react state. And I don't see cases where I am rendering invalid state.

Comment: You call `deletePhotos()` which I assume triggers a re-render. At this point, you would render the component where the state has all the photos that have just been deleted selected. Then, you call setState making no items selected.